# Send Form Data to mySQL Database After JavaScript Validation via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, validation

I have an html form used as a subscription form. The form is sent via POST method to PHP file for processing and database entry. Form validation is done via JavaScript.

I don't want to redirect to the PHP file and I want to keep my form styling. That is, when the user clicks on the SUBMIT button the form animates and displays a Success message on-page without reloading or sending to the php file.

I have tested the PHP file alone and it works fine, writing as expected in mySQL database table. 
The JavaScript validation file also works great on its own. The problem is that when the Submit button is clicked, after all required fields are valid, the form animates as if data is sent successfully, but no data gets written into my database. I tried inserting AJAX in different formats at different place in the JavaScript code but nothing worked.

The JS Validation file is linked to via  in the HTML file. And the PHP file is linked to via the Form Action="" attribute.

When I use the following script in the HTML alongside the link to form.js :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#submitBtn").click(function() {
    var dataString = $('#register').serialize();
    $.ajax({   
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "contact/validate.php",
                    data: dataString
            });

});
</script>
```

It actually works - the form animates as intended, there is no redirect to the PHP file and form data gets written into the database, but this makes dublicate entries and also allows non-valid entries to be written into the database, despite the JavaScript-initiated error messages on the input fields.

**Here is my HTML Form:**

```
 <div id="contactForm" class="contactForm">
<div id="formHeader" class="formHeader">
    <h2 id="message">Форма за регистрация</h2>
</div>
<div id="formBody" class="formBody">
    <form action="contact/validate.php" method="POST" name="contactForm"   id="register">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="inputContainer hlf">
            <input name="fullname" id="fullname" type="text" placeholder="Вашето име" minlength="2" maxlength="40" required tabindex="1">
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer hlf">
            <input name="location" id="location" type="text" placeholder="Населено място" minlength="5" maxlength="40" required tabindex="2">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="inputContainer hlf">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Ваш имейл за контакт" maxlength="75" required tabindex="3">
        </div>
            <div class="inputContainer hlf">
            <input name="phone" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон" pattern="[0-9 ]" maxlength="15" tabindex="4">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="4" placeholder="Допълнителен коментар" minlength="5" maxlength="250" tabindex="5"></textarea>
        </div></div>
        <input id="submitBtn" class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Изпрати">
    </form>
</div>
```

**Here is my PHP File:**

```
<?php
//Clean form data from backslashes and evil tags
//define variables and set to empty values
$fullname = $location = $email = $phone = $comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$fullname = test_input($_POST["fullname"]);
$location = test_input($_POST["location"]);
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
$phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

//All input is tested and validated, now connect to DB and send data to the    mySQL database table:

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "usename";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribed (fullname, location, email, phone, comment)
VALUES ('$fullname', '$location', '$email', '$phone', '$comment')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

**Finally, here is my JavaScript validation file:**

```
$(function() {
"use strict";
var //GLOBAL VARIABLES
input,
        container,
        //CSS CLASSES
        classSuccess = "success",
        classError = "error",
        //FORM VALIDATOR
        formValidator = {
            init: function() {
                this.cacheDom();
                this.bindEvents();
            },
            cacheDom: function() {
                //MAIN PARENT ELEMENT
                this.contactForm = document.getElementById("contactForm");
                //MAIN FORM ELEMENTS
                this.formHeader = document.querySelector("#formHeader h2");
                this.formBody = document.getElementById("formBody");
                this.inputContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("inputContainer");
                //USER INPUT ELEMENTS
                //INPUT FIELDS
                this.fields = {
                    fullname: document.getElementById("fullname"),
                    location: document.getElementById("location"),
                    email: document.getElementById("email")
                };
                this.submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
            },
            bindEvents: function() {
                var i;
                //RUN RULES ON SUBMIT BUTTON CLICK
                this.submitBtn.onclick = this.runRules.bind(this);
                //BIND EVENTS TO EACH INPUT FIELD
                for (i in this.fields) {
                    if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        //VARIABLES
                        input = this.fields[i];
                        container = input.parentElement;
                        //RUN RULES WHEN INPUT HAS FOCUS
                        input.onfocus = this.runRules.bind(this);
                        //RESET ERRORS WHEN CONTAINER IS CLICKED
                        container.onclick = this.resetErrors.bind(this, input);
                    }
                }
            },
            runRules: function(evnt) {
                var target = evnt.target,
                        type = evnt.type;
                //IF EVENT ON SUBMIT BUTTON
                if (target === this.submitBtn) {
                    //PREVENT FORM SUBMITTION
                    this.preventDefault(evnt);
                    //IF INPUT HAS FOCUS
                } else if (type === "focus") {
                    //RESET CLASSLIST
                    this.resetClassList(target.parentElement);
                    //RESET ERRORS
                    this.resetErrors(target);
                    return false;
                }
                //RESET CLASSLIST
                this.resetClassList();
                //CHECK FIELDS
                this.checkFields();
            },
            preventDefault: function(evnt) {
                //PREVENT DEFUALT
                evnt.preventDefault();
            },
            checkFields: function() {
                var i,
                        validCount = 0,
                        //EMAIL FILTER 
                        filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                //CYLCE THROUGH INPUTS
                for (i in this.fields) {
                    if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        input = this.fields[i];
                        //CHECK IF FIELD IS EMPTY
                        if (input.value === "") {
                            //ADD ERROR CLASS
                            this.addClass(input, classError);
                            //CHECK IF EMAIL IS VALID
                        } else if (i === "email" && !filter.test(input.value)) {
                            //ADD ERROR CLASS
                            this.addClass(input, classError);
                        } else {
                            //FIELD IS VALID
                            this.addClass(input, classSuccess);
                            validCount += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //IF ALL FIELDS ARE VALID
                if (validCount === 3) {
                    //SUBMIT FORM
                    this.submitForm();
                }
            },
            addClass: function(input, clss) {
                container = input.parentElement;
                //IF INPUT HAS ERROR
                if (clss === classError) {
                    //SHOW ERROR MESSAGE
                    this.errorMessage(input);
                }
                //ADD CLASS
                input.parentElement.classList.add(clss);
            },
            errorMessage: function(input) {
                var message;
                //IF NAME HAS ERROR
                if (input === this.fields.fullname) {
                    message = "Моля, въведете пълно име";
                    //ELSE IF LOCATION HAS ERROR 
                } else if (input === this.fields.location) {
                    message = "Моля, въведете град/село";
                    //ELSE IF USEREMAIL HAS ERROR
                } else if (input === this.fields.email) {
                    message = "Има грешка в имейла";
                }
                this.renderError(input, message);
            },
            renderError: function(input, message) {
                var html;
                //GET INPUT CONTAINER
                container = input.parentElement;
                //RENDER HTML
                html = document.createElement("div");
                html.setAttribute("class", "message");
                html.innerHTML = message;
                //IF MESSAGE ELEMENT DOESN'T EXIST
                if (!container.getElementsByClassName("message")[0]) {
                    //INSERT MESSAGE TO INPUT CONTAINER
                    container.insertBefore(html, container.firstElementChild);
                }
            },
            resetClassList: function(input) {
                var i;
                //IF TARGETING SPECIFIC INPUT
                if (input) {
                    //GET INPUT CONTAINER
                    container = input.parentElement;
                    //REMOVE CLASSES
                    container.classList.remove(classError, classSuccess);
                    //FOCUS ON INPUT FIELD
                    input.focus();
                } else {
                    for (i in this.fields) {
                        if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            //REMOVE CLASSES FROM ALL FIELDS
                            this.fields[i].parentElement.classList.remove(classError, classSuccess);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            resetErrors: function(input) {
                //GET INPUT CONTAINER
                container = input.parentElement;
                //IF CONTAINER CONTAINS ERROR
                if (container.classList.contains(classError)) {
                    //RESET CLASSES
                    this.resetClassList(input);
                }
            },
            submitForm: function() {
                var waitForAnimation;
                //ADD SUCCESS CLASS
                this.contactForm.classList.add(classSuccess);
                //WAIT FOR ANIMATION TO FINISH
                this.changeHeader("Регистрацията е успешна!");
                //WAIT FOR ANIMATION TO FINISH
                setTimeout(this.changeHeader.bind(this, "ДОБРЕ ДОШЛИ!"), 1800);
            },
            changeHeader: function(text) {
                //CHANGE HEADER TEXT
                this.formHeader.innerHTML = text;
            }
        };
//INITIATE FORM VALIDATOR
formValidator.init();
}());
```

Comment: Several points are not clear here. 1) Where is your JS validation file located and how is it launched? 2) In the script showed by your "The issue" paragraph, you don't do anything when success; more over your don't prevent default (so the form submits).

Comment: The JS Validation file is linked to via <script src="js/form.js"></script> in the HTML file. And the PHP file is linked to via the Form Action="" attribute.

What do you mean "you don't do anything when success" ? Please, I came here because I'm very novice with JavaScript and PHP. 

Also, as I pointed, the AJAX call within the HTML file does work and sends data to the database, but it bypasses the validation rules in the separate form.js file.

Comment: Your `$.ajax()` call **only** sends data to the database. It doesn' prevent click to finally result in submitting the form, so the `validate.php` script is executed twice: first by Ajax `url`, then by form `action`. To avoid this, you should add `return false;` at the end of your click function. Begin with that, then we can examine the `success` aspect.

Comment: Thank you for your time, cFreed! Much appreciated. :-)

So,  

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submitBtn").click(function() {
        var dataString = $('#register').serialize();
        $.ajax({   
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "contact/validate.php",
                        data: dataString
                });
   return false;
    });
    </script>

 This still has no effect in preventing invalid form data be written in the database.

Comment: After examining your JS Validation file more deeply I begin to understand: it's where you currently notify `preventDefault`. But here is the point: as this event handler (the one in Validation file) prevents default, the other one (where is the `$.ajax()` call) is not executed! In my mind Validation file, either does too much job, or at the opposit should include the `validation.php` invocation.

Comment: At a raw level, to avoid too much reorganization of your code, seems that you might try this: 1) add `return false;` after `$.ajax()` as already suggested; 2) suppress the `preventDefault` notification in the Validation file. So all should work fine.

Comment: This still has no effect in preventing invalid form data be written in the database.
With the script above situation is the following:

I have 3 required fields. I enter something into the first one and press Send. The form displays error messages for the remaining two fields. Then I enter some info in the second input field and press Send. Again, the form informs me that there is one more required field left. I enter the email address and press Send.

Comment: This time the form animates as it should and displays the Success message. However, in mySQL database table I have four separate entries with only the last one valid. 

What can the solution be?

Comment: If I delete this part: preventDefault: function(evnt) {
     //PREVENT DEFUALT
     evnt.preventDefault();
    },  The animation on my forms stops working. :(

Comment: Can you think of a valid way to include the validation.php invocation inside the JS Validation file ? In some IF statement after all the validation rules, I tried, but to no avail....

Comment: (Caution: I couldn't ensure to be really aware of all the job done in Validation file). That's said, from your last comment I'd suggest an alternative way: keep the `preventDefault` in Validation file, and add `$ajax()` inside it, at the place where all is checked and validated, whithout the previously proposed `return false;` (have no more sense in this context).

Comment: I tried adding it here ' //IF ALL FIELDS ARE VALID
     if (validCount === 3) {
      //SUBMIT FORM
      this.submitForm();
  var dataString = $('#register').serialize();
        $.ajax({   
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "contact/validate.php",
                        data: dataString
                });
     } '

The form displays Success message nice and animated without page reloads, but no records in the database.

Comment: I've trouble to understand how `submitForm()` is supposed to work: it should currently fire an JS error at the `this.changeHeader.bind()` point. So try putting `var dataString = ... , data: dataString});` **before** `this.submitForm();`.

Comment: See a working demo of the form here: [link](http://www.mindvolution.net/TEST.html)

Comment: I don't understand: what might I notice on the demo form? Notably I can't find your JS Validation script in it. In the other hand, have you tried my last suggestion?

Comment: The JS script is linked to from the bottom of the html file. I tried placing the AJAX call before the `this.submitForm();` : it made no difference. Still no record in the database

Comment: I continue not finding the validation script! In the other hand, I wanted to have a try with the form and I'm stuck on phone entry: from the HTML element I see that it must be only digits (max 15); and nothing else in the validation script. But entering 0123456789 is not accepted. What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to solve this with me! :) Please, be more specific as to what do you mean by "not finding the validation script!" ..? Despite that the phone input field is set as "tel" with pattern="[0-9 ] these seem inactive. However, I have no problem entering 0-9 into the phone input field and getting accepted.

Comment: There is something strange: I'm using Firefox with Firebug and it doesn't show anything after the comment "End Document, place <scripts> here". Then I had the idea to directly look at the source code and now I can see the scripts. But they are of type `rocketscript` (I didn't know that): seems that it makes Firebug fail to recognize them!

Comment: Only the first 3 input fields are required. That's why I have JS validation rules only for them. I just need to find a way to initiate an AJAX call to the validate.php script to send the form data from the input fields to my database table from within the JS validation file. While keeping all the other animation-related functionality of the JavaScript code

Comment: Really, do you think? I'm using CloudFlare CDN, it adds these tags `rocketscript` to scripts and other data into the html. Cloudflare has option to temporarily disable its caching services, so to be able to do development work on the website. At some point, I also began to wonder whether nothing seems to work because of the CDN servers... though this isn't very rational to think, since they do have a "development mode"

Comment: So, it seems that Firebug can't recognize Cloudflare-optimized script tags? What would that mean? (I haven't used Firebug, or other debugging software like that. Got to try:)

Comment: Well I now could find the validation script: from the Firebug point of view it's included in a `rocket.js` script. But I can't inspect nor debug it easily since it's compacted. In the other hand, using your information (only 3 first fields required) I could submit the form: the strange point is that I got a new page showing "New record created successfully". It means 1) that `validation.php` script was invoked, and apparently worked successfully; 2) that `preventDefault` didn't work!

Comment: At the point we're arrived, it should be debugged. But as exposed below it's not currently easy. Could you change the structure in order to (temporarily) **not** use CloudFlare for the validation script (insert a simple `<script>` tag in the `<header>`)?

Comment: Ahh, the issues only deepen. I see your entry in database. I opened Firefox to test. Indeed, now I see that upon submission the phone input becomes red (as if error). However, the form submits. But I see no entry from my submission in the database. Why would that be? ....So, now I disabled compression of files... you shoud see them fine. Although, I have included the complete JS Validation file, alongside the PHP file in my question above.

Comment: Yet another weird point: although you say you had disabled compression, recalling your `TEST.html` I get exactly the same contents (with the "hidden" scripts included in the `rocket.js` one)! And I checked it's not a cache issue in my browser.

Comment: Otherwise, did I correctly understand: You see my entry in the database, while you don't see the yours? It'd mean that different browsers contexts lead to different final behaviour... From this point of view it could only regard JS part.

Comment: I have to say that it is not convenient to do real-time development work on live website that uses a CDN service, even if it is "temporarily disabled". A lot of useless frustration. Now, THANK YOU VERY MUCH for your help! Although, I did think this solution up two days ago, for some inexplicable reasons, I couldn't make it work then. Now after clearing cache and what not, I can confirm that the JS Validation works and successfully and correctly write into the Database via the PHP file!

Comment: This part did it: `//IF ALL FIELDS ARE VALID
     if (validCount === 3) {
      //SUBMIT FORM
                        var dataString = $('#register').serialize();
                        $.ajax({   
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "contact/validate.php",
                        data: dataString
                });
      this.submitForm();
     }
    },`

But I had trouble noticing it worked, due to stubborn-cache issues. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Glad to help. What is actually frustrating is not to know exactly why it didn't work with the before last version... In case of useful (even if not related), note that with Firebug I'm notified of these errors when calling `TEST.html`: 1) "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mindvolution.net/css/hover.css"; 2) something wrong with `cloudfare.min.js` (without diagnosis).

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Task 1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#submit").click(function()
            {
                if($("#fname").val()=="")
                {
                    alert("First name missing");
                    return false;
                }
                if($("#lname").val()=="")
                {
                    alert("Last name missing");
                    return false;
                }
                var x= jQuery("input[name=gender]:checked").val();
                if(!x)
                {
                    alert("Gender missing");
                    return false;
                }
                var x= jQuery("input[type=checkbox]:checked").val();
                if (!x)
                {
                    alert("Hobbies not selected");
                    return false;
                }
                if($("#education").val()=="") 
                {
                    alert("Select Education");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="POST" name="myform">
    <table border="2" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Enter first name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Enter last name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Select gender:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender">Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Select hobbies:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="cricket" id="hobby">Cricket
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="hockey">Hockey
                <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="swimming">Swimming
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Select education:           
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="education" id="education">
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
                    <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
                    <option value="BE">BE</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: some description to point out/explain the posted code would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a good one. Though, what I needed was email check and also adding min. characters check, so to make sure the data sent to database is valid, not just some random typing.